# Unable to run command in remote server using ssh

Tags: shell-script

I want to remote using ssh and execute the grep command for a pattern search.

using the below script but its not working. Please suggest.

```
read -p "please enter the pattern:" pattern
host=hostname
ssh $host -t 'cd /path ; zgrep $pattern *| grep Status=completed;
```

Comment: You do not feel like telling us what the pattern looks like and what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
read -p "please enter the pattern:" pattern
host=hostname
ssh $host -t 'cd /path ; zgrep $pattern *| grep Status=completed;
```

1. The `read` should probably be `read -r -p ... pattern` so that backslashes are read properly.
2. It is unclear whether you use `hostname` as a placeholder for the actual host name (which I presume) or whether you believe that `host` will get the value of executing the `hostname` utility.
3. The last line has a unterminated single quoted string.  Even if it was terminated with a single quote at the end, the `$pattern` variable would not be expanded due to the single quotes. The `cd` is unnecessary. The `$host` variable expansion needs quoting and command line flags should come before the host name (but in this case `-t` is not needed).

Suggestion:

```
read -r -p "please enter the pattern:" pattern
host=hostname
ssh "$host" find /path -type f -name "'*.gz'" -exec zgrep -e "'$pattern'" /dev/null {} '\;' | grep -F 'Status=completed;'
```

The `find` command here will look for all `*.gz` files under `/path` on the remote host and use `zgrep` to look for the pattern in `$pattern` in those files. The result is then further filtered (locally) by the last `grep`. I was unsure whether the `;` should be part of that last pattern or not.  Delete it if it shouldn't be there.

The funky quoting with `"'*.gz'"` and `"'$pattern'"` is required.  The local shell with strip off the first layer of quotes before calling `ssh`, leaving `'*.gz'` and `'...'` (whatever the value of `$pattern` is) for the `find` command on the remote side.

With `zgrep ... /dev/null ...` we ensure that `zgrep` will always be handed at least two files (`/dev/null` and another file from `/path`), so that the file names of matching files will be present in its output.

`grep -F` will treat the given string as a fixed string rather than as a regular expression. It serves here as both documentation and to speed up the processing.

Comment: "The $host variable expansion needs quoting" - How many people know what they have to do in order to be able to use something there that would have to be quoted? Thus I find your "needs" a bit strong. Something else: May I assume that you have not tried that `ssh` call? ;-)

Comment: @HaukeLaging If I did a core review of shell code using unquoted variable expansions, I would comment on them. Also, the `ssh` won't work (the `find`, actually) but I'll fix that in two secs (now done).

Comment: Now there are only three quoting errors left... The same problem every time: The `ssh` call removes the first quoting layer. So the command line sees an unquoted `*.gz`, an unquoted `$pattern` and an unquoted `;` at the very end.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Ah, I now see what you're trying to get at. The `;` at the end should be ok now. The strings needs an extra layer of quoting.

Comment: I just realize  didn't look thorougly enough: Yes, it should work now - but is it intentional that you execute one `grep` remotely and the other one locally? Seems to me that potentially a lot of data is needlessly transferred.

Comment: @HaukeLaging The local `grep` was intentional. Yes, if one expected megabytes of results from the `zgrep`, it would be better to run the last `grep` remotely. The whole thing would also be able to be solved with a shell script on the remote side, without the need for quoting wizardry.